# Merging the Not Missing Observation also in the final Table and transpose the final Output

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have 10 different variables in 10 different tables with the VARNAME and MISSING PERCENT.

Out of these 10, lets say 5 do not have the "MISSING PERCENT" and I want to include these observation with 0% Missing. For now, it eliminates this observation in the final output.

```
data Final_Output_All_Missing;
length VARNAME $ 30;

merge work.Final_Output_MOLD work.Final_output_tbm_stage2
work.final_output_article7 
 work.final_output_tbm_stage1 work.final_output_bladder 
work.final_output_batch_id;
by varname;
 keep VARNAME PERCENT;
run;

VARNAME              MISSING PERCENT

BLADDER               0.10
MOLD                  0.06
TBM_STAGE1            0.18
TBM_STAGE2            99.9
```

Secondly, I have already merged the different tables containing different variables(0% still needs to be merged) as shown below:

After merging, I want to see the output in this format. is it possible for me to get in this format?

```
         BLADDER      MOLD    TBM_STAGE1   TBM_STAGE2

1.       0.10%        0.06%     0.18%       99.9%
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Does my answer below transpose your data  as you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Code below will:**

- Replace missing values with 0 (I added missing values in the data)
- Adds Percent format xx.xx%
- Transpose the data

**Code:**

```
/*Create input data*/
data have;
informat VARNAME $10.;
input VARNAME $ MISSING_PERCENT  ;
length VARNAME $10;
datalines;
BLADDER  0.10
MOLD 0.06
TBM_STAGE1 0.18
TBM_STAGE2 99.9
TBM_STAGE3  . 
TBM_STAGE4  . 
;;;;;;
run;
/*Replace missing values with 0, and Add % format */
proc sql;
create table work.new as 
select
VARNAME,
coalesce(MISSING_PERCENT,0)/100 as MISSING_PERCENT format=percent8.2
from work.have;
quit;
/*Transpose Data*/
proc transpose data=work.new
               out=work.want name=VARNAME;
               id VARNAME;
run;
```

**Input:**

[image: INput]

**Formatted:**

[image: Formatted]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. It is perfectly giving what I want.
But, I do have a list of 160 Variables and I think to hard code it, will take more effort. What I did is I excluded the Variables which have 0% Missing Percent and extracted the ones which have missing percent.

This is how I did it to extract the Missing Percent:

```
> data Final_Output_&var;
                set Final_Output_&var;
                VARNAME = "&var";
            %if &t=char %then
                    %do;
                        where put (&var., $missfmt.) in ("Missing");
                    %end;
            %else
                    %do;
                        where put (&var., missfmt.) in ("Missing");
                    %end;
        run;
```

Thanks again for your quick reply !!!
Best Regards,
Pankaj